# Is there an IC which converts I2C/UART/SPI (or any standard communication interface) commands directly to DALI2 format?

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, dali, bit-bang

Is there an IC which converts I2C/ UART/ SPI commands (or any standard communication interface) directly to DALI2 format? DALI seems similar to 1.2k baud UART in a sense, but is encoded in Manchester format and has its own start/stop bits. I'd like to reduce SW development for DALI driver bit-banging if possible by using a DALI-capable chip.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because DALI is not normal UART as it is Manchester encoded, start/stop conditions aside. Also, same reason as why I'm looking for a dedicated chip for DALI comms is to avoid bit-banging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microchip have some parts that support DALI such as [PIC18F26K83](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC18F26K83) using a modified UART peripheral. You still need the high voltage and polarity insensitive interface circuit externally but this could simplify your design.

Whether this is suitable depends on your application. I believe it can be used for control gear (slave) and for single master with receive capabilities, but if you need multi-mastering as defined in IEC62386-101 then check with them - the data sheet isn't clear how it copes with timing windows defined in the standard.

Comment: Good find! This component would ease SW development, thank you. I also found another chip (https://www.codemercs.com/downloads/ledwarrior/LW14_Datasheet.pdf) which features I2C-to-DALI, but for some reason, I could not find it from Farnell or Mouser or Digikey, so I'm going for the Microchip part.

Answer (score 1):

Infineon has IC's and kits for Dali. Since it is a mix of technology low V uC and AC rectifiers, it's not just an IC.

https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/search.html#!term=dali-2&view=all

https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application_Lighting_Digital_Addressable_Lighting_Interface_%28DALI%29_Control_Gear-TR-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625696ed76015698e9d86c7cc5